# How to break too long chapter title into multiple lines?

Tags: line-breaking, titlesec

I have titleformat for chapter title specified like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter \quad \MakeUppercase{#1}}{.5em}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Too long chapter name needs to be split into multiple lines}

\end{document}
```

Now my chapter title is too long so it cannot be displayed well in one line and needs to be splitted into multiple lines. Ive tried adding `\\` or `\newline` but without success.

```
\chapter{Too long chapter name needs to be split into multiple lines}
```

[image]
How can I split this title into multiple lines? Ive tried to search for similar questions but couldnt find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting the title in the wrong place:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Too long chapter name needs to be split into multiple lines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `explicit` it can be

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the optional argument `[display]` will work. Section 3.1 of the [titlesec documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}%
  {\thechapter \quad \MakeUppercase{#1}}{.5em}{} % Succeeds
%\titleformat{\chapter}%
%  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
%  {\thechapter \quad \MakeUppercase{#1}}{.5em}{} % Fails

\begin{document}

\chapter{Too long chapter name needs to be split into multiple lines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `[display]` argument just added a big space after my chapter title but it remained in one line.... could there be a problem with other packages I am using? Should I post them to question?

Comment: Verify my answer works as-is (I'm pretty sure it does), and if that's not fixing your actual document, there you'll need to start narrowing down the conflicting package or setting.

Comment: There is a problem with `explicit`. When I remove it and change the command to:
`\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{.5em}{}` then the result is as I wanted, split into multiple lines but I dont know how can I make it uppercase now. (I dont even need to add `display` because when I do it puts number on one line and chapter title on new line under the number.)

Comment: Normally, `display` is for chapter number and chapter title on different lines. What you obtain corresponds more to the `block` style.